# Flag for debugging is recorded as "not suitable for this site" on profile

Tags: bug, flags

Usually when I flag a question for requiring "debugging information" (say, due to lack of code and/or reproducible example, desired output, etc) then it is recorded in my flag history as "needs details or clarity" or "requires debugging information", or something to that effect. Both make sense.

Lately (last half an hour), a couple of debugging flags I raised were listed in my flag history as "not suitable for this site", which I think does not really fit the original flag and could itself be a separate flag entirely.

What is the reason for this classification? Is this a bug, or is it normal?
I definitely clicked the right (debugging) flag option as I tested it one more time after noticing this issue.

An example:
[image]